# I failed to get LEMP running with docker-machine and docker-compose

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, docker-compose, docker-machine

I created a docker-machine under MacOS in the following way:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox temp.sysadmin.local
docker-machine env temp.sysadmin.local
eval $(docker-machine env temp.sysadmin.local)
docker-machine ip
192.168.99.100
```

Visiting `http://192.168.99.100/` in the browser I got the following message

> Welcome to nginx!
>   If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.
>
> For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
>   Commercial support is available at nginx.com.
>
> Thank you for using nginx.

My `public/index.php` looks like below which did not show up rather it I got the above message:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!";

$con = mysqli_connect(192.168.99.100,"mgsv_user","mgsvpass","mgsv");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  else {
         echo "done";
  }
?>
```

Visiting `http://192.168.99.100:8183` in the browser I got the message that the site could not be reached.

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
nginx:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    links:
        - phpfpm
    volumes:
        - ./nginx/default:/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
        - ./nginx/default:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

        - ./logs/nginx-error.log:/var/log/nginx/error.log
        - ./logs/nginx-access.log:/var/log/nginx/access.log

phpfpm:
    build: ./mGSV
    restart: always
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
        - ./public:/usr/share/nginx/html

mysql:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=mgsv
          - MYSQL_USER=mgsv_user
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mgsvpass
    ports:
          - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
          - ./mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  restart: always
  links:
    - mysql
  ports:
    - 8183:80
  environment:
    PMA_USER: root
    PMA_PASSWORD: admin
    PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
```

My `./nginx/default` looks like this:

```
server {
    listen  80;

    # this path MUST be exactly as docker-compose.fpm.volumes,
    # even if it doesn't exists in this dock.
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.html;

    server_name 192.168.99.100;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass phpfpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

My `mysql/mysql.sql` looks like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mgsv;
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'mgsv_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mgsvpass';
use mgsv;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userinfo` (
        `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `email` text NOT NULL,
        `hash` text NOT NULL,
        `synfilename` text NOT NULL,
        `annfilename` text NOT NULL,
        `url` text NOT NULL,
        `session_id` text NOT NULL,
        `annImage`   int(5) NOT NULL,
        `create_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

Finally, my `mGSV/Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM php:5-fpm
```

This is the output which I got after running `docker-compose up --build`

```
Creating mgsvdocker2_phpfpm_1     ... done
Status: Downloaded newer image for phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
Creating mgsvdocker2_mysql_1      ... done
Creating mgsvdocker2_nginx_1      ... done
Creating mgsvdocker2_phpmyadmin_1 ... 
Creating mgsvdocker2_phpmyadmin_1 ... done
Attaching to mgsvdocker2_phpfpm_1, mgsvdocker2_mysql_1, mgsvdocker2_phpmyadmin_1, mgsvdocker2_nginx_1
mysql_1       | Initializing database
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:05.763493Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:06.324162Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:06.451997Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:06.529366Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: ea0b56ed-3082-11e8-a16b-0242ac110003.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:06.535219Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
phpmyadmin_1  | 2018-03-25 23:19:06,853 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
phpmyadmin_1  | 2018-03-25 23:19:06,854 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor.d/nginx.ini" during parsing
phpmyadmin_1  | 2018-03-25 23:19:06,854 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor.d/php.ini" during parsing
phpmyadmin_1  | 2018-03-25 23:19:06,875 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
phpmyadmin_1  | 2018-03-25 23:19:06,876 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
phpmyadmin_1  | 2018-03-25 23:19:06,878 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
phpmyadmin_1  | 2018-03-25 23:19:07,882 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 20
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:06.536405Z 1 [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:08.072381Z 1 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:08.073136Z 1 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:08.073808Z 1 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:08.074622Z 1 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:08.075177Z 1 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:08.076188Z 1 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:08.076917Z 1 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
phpmyadmin_1  | 2018-03-25 23:19:07,886 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 21
phpmyadmin_1  | 2018-03-25 23:19:08,991 INFO success: php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:08.077706Z 1 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | Database initialized
mysql_1       | Initializing certificates
mysql_1       | Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
mysql_1       | .................................+++
mysql_1       | ..................................................+++
mysql_1       | unable to write 'random state'
mysql_1       | writing new private key to 'ca-key.pem'
mysql_1       | -----
mysql_1       | Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
mysql_1       | ......................................+++
mysql_1       | ........................+++
mysql_1       | unable to write 'random state'
mysql_1       | writing new private key to 'server-key.pem'
mysql_1       | -----
mysql_1       | Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
mysql_1       | ...........................................................+++
mysql_1       | .........................................................................................+++
mysql_1       | unable to write 'random state'
mysql_1       | writing new private key to 'client-key.pem'
mysql_1       | -----
mysql_1       | Certificates initialized
mysql_1       | MySQL init process in progress...
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.143460Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.149174Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.21) starting as process 87 ...
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.156556Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.157353Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.158011Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.158523Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.159175Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.159675Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.161357Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.163695Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.167203Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.179676Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.184909Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.196281Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.216415Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.217396Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.265675Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.266735Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.266755Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.267162Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.318014Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.21 started; log sequence number 2551166
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.320133Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.321120Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.328645Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 180325 23:19:12
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.331857Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.332980Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.344408Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.345306Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.346038Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.346698Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.347274Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.347891Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.352608Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.353595Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.364997Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:12.365881Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
mysql_1       | Version: '5.7.21'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
mysql_1       | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysql_1       | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysql_1       | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysql_1       | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.658088Z 4 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.658826Z 4 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.659495Z 4 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.660170Z 4 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.660880Z 4 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.661453Z 4 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.662267Z 4 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.662993Z 4 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql_1       | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql_1       | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql_1       | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.703300Z 8 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.704110Z 8 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.704970Z 8 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.705817Z 8 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.706327Z 8 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.707081Z 8 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.708035Z 8 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.709023Z 8 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 
mysql_1       | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mgsv.sql
mysql_1       | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql_1       | 
mysql_1       | 
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.742703Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.743537Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.744235Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.744735Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.745891Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.747216Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.748406Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.749160Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750001Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750132Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750459Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750487Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750517Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750538Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750558Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750576Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750594Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750612Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750631Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750649Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750668Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750686Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750705Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750723Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750742Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750760Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750778Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750797Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750815Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750834Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750852Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750871Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750917Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750938Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750957Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750975Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.750995Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.751023Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.751056Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.751087Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.751116Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.751148Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.751180Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.753067Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.753266Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.853953Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:15.854563Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 180325 23:19:15
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.175698Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 12318753
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.178577Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.179402Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.179810Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.180344Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.180682Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.181331Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.182518Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
mysql_1       | 
mysql_1       | 
mysql_1       | MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
mysql_1       | 
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.448053Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.450016Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.21) starting as process 1 ...
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.454525Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.455105Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.455758Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.456143Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.456633Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.457330Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.458460Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.459372Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.462314Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.474111Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.477547Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.490862Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.504688Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.505537Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.536380Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.538414Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.539202Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.540456Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.591603Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.21 started; log sequence number 12318753
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.593669Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.601501Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.602903Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.610550Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 180325 23:19:17
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.611797Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.614570Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.615283Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.616517Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.617454Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.626181Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.627017Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.629108Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.630182Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mgsv_user@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.631071Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.631802Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.632706Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.635780Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.636738Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1       | 2018-03-25T23:19:17.646310Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do your nginx configs look like?

Comment: My nginx config (`./nginx/default`) is posted in my question above or do I need any other config files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default nginx config is in another place. Use this:

```
volumes:
        - ./nginx/default:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```